# How to Convert Hexdecimal code to color in windows 8

Tags: windows-runtime

I have code Hexadecimal code "FFB800" and I needed to convert to "Color" in WinRT.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: From what I've found so far, it appears that you can only create a `Color` in WinRT from separate RGB components. So you can parse this to an int, then separate out the bytes, then create a `Color` (which will, probably, internally combine them to a single int again..)

Comment: I wonder why would anyone downvote this question... especially without a comment and by losing reputation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the purpose of the question? Is it an option to do this in plain XAML? XAML does take Hexadecimal codes.

```xml
    <Grid Background="#FFB800">
```

Otherwise in code-behind I've used more or less the following in a Windows 8 App:

```cs
    var hexCode = "#FFFFB800";
    var color = new Color();
    color.A = byte.Parse(hexCode.Substring(1, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    color.R = byte.Parse(hexCode.Substring(3, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    color.G = byte.Parse(hexCode.Substring(5, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    color.B = byte.Parse(hexCode.Substring(7, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```

Answer (score 3):

The short way to do it in a tweet:

```
(Color)XamlReader.Load(string.Format("<Color xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation …\">{0}</Color>", c));
```

The recommended way is to get [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit) from NuGet and call

```
WinRTXamlToolkit.Imaging.ColorExtensions.FromString(c);
```

This runs way faster than using `XamlReader`, so it is recommended if you need to call it more than once. You can also clone it from [GitHub](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit/Imaging/ColorExtensions.cs) or copy and paste from here:

```
#region FromString()
/// <summary>
/// Returns a Color based on XAML color string.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="c">The color string. Any format used in XAML should work.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Color FromString(string c)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(c))
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid color string.", "c");

    if (c[0] == '#')
    {
        switch (c.Length)
        {
            case 9:
            {
                //var cuint = uint.Parse(c.Substring(1), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                var cuint = Convert.ToUInt32(c.Substring(1), 16);
                var a = (byte)(cuint >> 24);
                var r = (byte)((cuint >> 16) & 0xff);
                var g = (byte)((cuint >> 8) & 0xff);
                var b = (byte)(cuint & 0xff);

                return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
            }
            case 7:
            {
                var cuint = Convert.ToUInt32(c.Substring(1), 16);
                var r = (byte)((cuint >> 16) & 0xff);
                var g = (byte)((cuint >> 8) & 0xff);
                var b = (byte)(cuint & 0xff);

                return Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b);
            }
            case 5:
            {
                var cuint = Convert.ToUInt16(c.Substring(1), 16);
                var a = (byte)(cuint >> 12);
                var r = (byte)((cuint >> 8) & 0xf);
                var g = (byte)((cuint >> 4) & 0xf);
                var b = (byte)(cuint & 0xf);
                a = (byte)(a << 4 | a);
                r = (byte)(r << 4 | r);
                g = (byte)(g << 4 | g);
                b = (byte)(b << 4 | b);

                return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
            }
            case 4:
            {
                var cuint = Convert.ToUInt16(c.Substring(1), 16);
                var r = (byte)((cuint >> 8) & 0xf);
                var g = (byte)((cuint >> 4) & 0xf);
                var b = (byte)(cuint & 0xf);
                r = (byte)(r << 4 | r);
                g = (byte)(g << 4 | g);
                b = (byte)(b << 4 | b);

                return Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b);
            }
            default:
                throw new FormatException(string.Format("The {0} string passed in the c argument is not a recognized Color format.", c));
        }
    }
    else if (
        c.Length > 3 &&
        c[0] == 's' &&
        c[1] == 'c' &&
        c[2] == '#')
    {
        var values = c.Split(',');

        if (values.Length == 4)
        {
            var scA = double.Parse(values[0].Substring(3));
            var scR = double.Parse(values[1]);
            var scG = double.Parse(values[2]);
            var scB = double.Parse(values[3]);

            return Color.FromArgb(
                (byte)(scA * 255),
                (byte)(scR * 255),
                (byte)(scG * 255),
                (byte)(scB * 255));
        }
        else if (values.Length == 3)
        {
            var scR = double.Parse(values[0].Substring(3));
            var scG = double.Parse(values[1]);
            var scB = double.Parse(values[2]);

            return Color.FromArgb(
                255,
                (byte)(scR * 255),
                (byte)(scG * 255),
                (byte)(scB * 255));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new FormatException(string.Format("The {0} string passed in the c argument is not a recognized Color format (sc#[scA,]scR,scG,scB).", c));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var prop = typeof(Colors).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(c);
        return (Color)prop.GetValue(null);
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: You don't need those `& 0xff`'s btw, the cast to `byte` already takes care of that

Answer (score 1):

```
        var hexCode = "#FFFFB800";
        var color = new Color();
        color.A = byte.Parse(hexCode.Substring(7, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        color.R = byte.Parse(hexCode.Substring(1, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        color.G = byte.Parse(hexCode.Substring(3, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        color.B = byte.Parse(hexCode.Substring(5, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```

how to set as fill for a xaml rectangle object

rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(color);

the other solution like this one works but returns the Parameters out of order
if you have only a 6 digit hex rather than the full 8 simply set the a to 255

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public struct MyColor : Windows.UI.Color
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert hexdecimal value into color.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hexCode">hexdecimal of color.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush ColorToBrush(string hexCode)
    {
        hexCode = hexCode.Replace("#", "");

        if (hexCode.Length == 6)
            return new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.ColorHelper.FromArgb(255,
                byte.Parse(hexCode.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
                byte.Parse(hexCode.Substring(2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
                byte.Parse(hexCode.Substring(4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)));
        else if (hexCode.Length == 8)
        {
            var color = new Windows.UI.Color();
            color.A = byte.Parse(hexCode.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
            color.R = byte.Parse(hexCode.Substring(2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
            color.G = byte.Parse(hexCode.Substring(4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
            color.B = byte.Parse(hexCode.Substring(6, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```