# How to save Status bar background colour in Local settings

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have given the user the freedom to change background colour and save it in local settings. But I am confused on how to save the status bar colour settings because I want to give the user freedom to choose from 4-5 colours where background of status bar can be changed.

Any suggestion?

Comment: @aloisdg I cant figure out. I tried making a variable of status bar in App.xaml.cs but I cant figure out what to do further. Please suggest

Comment: @aloisdg both links are for application bar. I need help for status bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public static void SaveStatusBarColor()
{
    // get status bar color
    var statusBar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
    var color = statusBar.BackgroundColor;

    // convert color to hex string
    var hexCode = color.HasValue ? color.Value.ToString() : "";

    // store color in local settings
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["StatusBarColor"] = hexCode;
}

public static void LoadStatusBarColor()
{
    // get color hex string from local settings
    var hexCode = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["StatusBarColor"] as string;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hexCode))
        return;

    // convert hexcode to color
    var color = new Color();
    color.A = byte.Parse(hexCode.Substring(1, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    color.R = byte.Parse(hexCode.Substring(3, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    color.G = byte.Parse(hexCode.Substring(5, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    color.B = byte.Parse(hexCode.Substring(7, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

    // set the status bar color
    var statusBar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
    statusBar.BackgroundColor = color;
}
```

---

Remember, `StatusBar.BackgroundOpacity` is initially 0, so you'll need to set it to 1 for the background color to have any effect.

Hexcode to color conversion code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16815300/734040.

Comment: I have tried your code and initially the code runs and saves the current status bar color.But when I again run the code on the line var statusBar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView() I get exception saying System.AccessViolationException. I have used the save code in my xaml page and LoadStatusBarColor code in app.xaml.cs @DecadeMoon

Comment: That's odd. It could be a bug. Anyway, you probably shouldn't put `LoadStatusBarColor()` in your app constructor, put it in your `App.OnLaunched()` override instead.

Comment: Yes it worked. Btw why we have to put in app loader rather than constructor. Can you explain a bit to me @Decade Moon

Comment: My guess was that the current [ApplicationView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview) hasn't been created yet in the app constructor. Even calling [ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.getforcurrentview) also throws an exception in the app constructor.